# Impossible to load file or assembly TemplateWizardInterface when creating a Data Connector projet in VS CE 2019

Tags: visual-studio, powerbi, visual-studio-2019

Using Visual Studio Community Edition 2019, I am trying to create a Power BI Data connector with the Power Query SQK.

My VS install is fresh, nothing installed except strict minimum (I did not chose anything when Visual Studio Installer proposed).

After installing, I juste downloaded the SDK (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dakahn.PowerQuerySDK&ssr=false#overview), double clicked on the file and it installed itself.

Back in VS, I want to create a project. I select Data Connector Project:

[image]

Then, I give it a name, click "Create" and I have this error message:

[image]

It says:

> Impossible to load the file or the assembly
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizardInterface`...`or one of its
> dependances. The file cannot be found

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the problem, open up Visual studio Installer, modify the current VS version you have, go in the "individual components" tab, filter the search with "sdk visual studio". The SDK is (for me) at the end of the list. Install it and problem is solved.